# Process form data before creating table entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

**Backstory:** I'm building a site that takes in a Soundcloud URL as part of a post. Currently, I store the link they provide and, when a user loads their feed view, I retrieve the associated image / title / favorite count etc. via my post_helper. I have quickly come to realize that this is not scalable and is hurting load times.

So, what I think I should do (feel free to tell me that there is a better way), is to retrieve the SC/YT metadata on form submit and store it along with the other post data (id, user, content etc.) in the posts' table entry. How would I go about calling the helper methods to retrieve such on form submit and include the metadata in the submitted params?

post_helper.rb excerpt:

```
def soundcloud_info(soundcloud_url, type)  
    begin
        resolve = scClient.get('/resolve', :url => soundcloud_url)
        track_info = scClient.get("/tracks/#{resolve.id}")
    rescue Soundcloud::ResponseError => e
        %Q{ Error: #{e.message}, Status Code: #{e.response.code} }
    end                 
    if type == "title"
        %Q{#{track_info['title']}}
    elsif type == "image"
        %Q{#{track_info['artwork_url']}}
    elsif type == "favCount"
        %Q{Favorite count: #{track_info['favoritings_count']}}              
    end
end
```

post_controler.rb excerpt:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Your post was successful!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's pretty straight forward... all I need to do is modify the parameters in the **controller** before I call @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post]). My issue was that I was trying to do so in the helper.

I haven't quite adapted the whole thing to get all my required fields, but here's an example of how I have adapted the create method to pull the api URL out if someone submits SoundCloud's embed iframe.

micropost_controller.rb excerpt:

```
def create
  @url = params[:post][:link_html]

  if @url[/^.*src="(https|http):\/\/w.soundcloud.com\/player\/\?url=(.*)">/] 
    params[:post][:link_html] = CGI::unescape($2)
  end

  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Your post was successful!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```